# CumulusRDF Update Query

Tags: rest, sparql, rdf

I'm trying to insert data my CumulusRDF via REST.

Problem: If i'm doing a query, it works nice, with the GET method

Ex: A simple query:

```
select * 
where
{ 
  ?s ?p ?o.
}
```

GET method:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/sparql-results' 'http://localhost:9090/cumulus/sparql?query=select+*+where+%7B%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo.%7D&accept=text%2Fhtml'
```

But, when i try to insert data, it fails.

Query:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
INSERT DATA
{ 
  <http://example/book1> dc:title "Harry Potter".
}
```

POST method:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/sparql-query' 'http://localhost:9090/cumulus/sparql?query=PREFIX+dc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0AINSERT+DATA%0A%7B+%0A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample%2Fbook1%3E+dc%3Atitle+%22Harry+Potter%22.%0A%7D
```

Erro:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

What i'm doing wrong? CumulusRDF is instaled in a Docker with Apache Cassandra DB.

Answer (score 3):

In SPARQL queries are not updates.   There are two separate languages.

If you use the HTTP query string, content-type is irrelevant. It should be`?update=`.

Better is to POST with the update in the HTTP body and using

`Content-Type: application/sparql-update`